# Mobile app: Persistent login (with two authentication method)

Tags: ios, facebook, web-services, authentication, mobile

I am designing a mobile app which has the following features:

1. The first time a user opens the app it is ask to authenticate himself to the app web service by signing in/up using a classical username/password schema or to use Facebook login.
2. Then, the next time it opens the app, the user won't have to enter its credential again and is automatically sign in.

The first authentication method is implemented. The web service sends back an authentication token that the user use to authenticate himself. The latter is stored together with the user ID in a non-volatile (protected) storage of the mobile.

I know lots of apps provide the two authentication method we are talking about. I was wondering how it is usually combine with the Facebook authentication. At the moment, I was thinking of generating credentials after Facebook login and authenticating Facebook users to my web service as if they were classical users. The users would be stored in the same web-service database table. Note that a flag in the database would tell us whether the user used Facebook or not for login, for if a user logs with the same Facebook account (identified by e-mail) on another device there won't be duplicate.

EDIT: Moreover, some apps let Facebook user to play with their Facebook friends for instance, but how is it done in a persistent manner since one can only have a temporary access token to query Facebook API ? More generally, how some apps do to keep the FB session persistent?

Do you think it is viable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook Access Tokens are of two types: short term and long term ones. You probably have played with the short term ones, but Facebook documentations say [[1]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) that normally mobile apps use the long term one.

> Native mobile applications using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.

iOS Facebook SDK [[2]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps#sdk) has a sample about maintaining session, sample is coming in the installation package of the bundle. (Same code also at GitHub[[3]](https://github.com/Citrrus/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample).) Here is the most essential part from the GitHub one:

```
SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
   // Open new session
}
```

Once the session is restored / found active with `isOpen`, there is no line of code in the example to refresh it. I am not an iOS programmer but for me that quoted paragraph from documentation and that code snippet from tutorial show I think clearly, that no other action to refresh is even needed, only successful use within about 60 days.

In short, you cannot have a permanent token lasting forever, but luckily enough you have almost one, if you just keep your users using the app in enough frequent manner.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens 
[2] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps#sdk

 [3] https://github.com/Citrrus/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample